# Taking Python class method as a polymorphic function

Tags: python, polymorphism, function-reference

Edit: this question is based on two mistakes: not originally yincluding `self` in methods and assuming unbounded methods would not exhibit polymorphism, but they do. I voted to close it.

I can take a method as a function-valued object in Python:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        return "Hi, I'm A.foo"

f = A.foo
a = A()
print(f(a))
```

produces `Hi, I'm A.foo`.

So far so good. However, `f` won't work for sub-classes:

```
class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        return "Hi, I'm B.foo"

f = A.foo
b = B()
f(b)
```

still produces `Hi, I'm A.foo`, whereas `b.foo()` produces `Hi, I'm B.foo`. In other words, polymorphism does not apply.

Question: is there a way to get a function-valued object in `f` so that `f(x) == x.foo()` whenever `isinstance(x, A)`?

In other words, how do I complete the snippet below for things to work?

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        return "Hi, I'm A.foo"

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        return "Hi, I'm B.foo"

f = <WHAT DO I PUT HERE?>
a = A()
b = B()
assert f(a) == a.foo()
assert f(b) == b.foo()
```

Comment: `f = lambda obj: obj.foo()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can pull the class name out like so:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        return "Hi, I'm {}.foo".format(self.__class__.__name__)

class B(A):
    def foo(self):
        return "Hi, I'm {}.foo".format(self.__class__.__name__)

f = A.foo  # this could be A or B, doesn't matter
a = A()
b = B()
assert f(a) == a.foo()
assert f(b) == b.foo()
```

Note that because B inherits from A, you don't even need the foo method there:

```
class A:
    def foo(self):
        return "Hi, I'm {}.foo".format(self.__class__.__name__)

class B(A):
    pass

f = A.foo
a = A()
b = B()
assert f(a) == a.foo()
assert f(b) == b.foo()
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I inferred that this didn't work based on some more complicated code, but the problem must be elsewhere. I should have run my example first.